# How to avoid strange whitespaces in django template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm using django template to render my webpage. In the process of unrolling the recursive tree something strange happens (and spaceless tag doesn't help).

This is my recursive template:

index.html:

```
<ul class="Container">
    <li class="IsRoot">
        <div class="Expand">

        </div>

        <div class="Content">
            Содержание
        </div>



    </li>

    {% include 'list.html' with data=list %}

</ul>
```

and list.html (as a recursive part):

```
<ul class="Container">
    <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
        <div class="Expand"></div>
        <div class="Content">
            <a href="/help/{{data.name}}">
                {{data.content}}
            </a>
        </div>
        {% for item in data.decendent %}
            {% include 'list.html' with data=item %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the result:

[image: strange behavior]

The html content of file which had been read as a content of html-file using open("index.html", 'r').read() was extracted as a text, not html:

```
<div id="frame" style="float:left; margin-left:310px;">
        &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
        &lt;html&gt;
            &lt;head&gt;
                &lt;title&gt;hello&lt;/title&gt;
            &lt;/head&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;
                Body Great Style
            &lt;/body&gt;
        &lt;/html&gt;
</div>
```

And also I have strange whitespaces between the elements:

[image]

How to avoid this strange behavior? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`{% spaceless %}` removes only whitespace between tags, not in text. It is described in docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

If you want remove whitespaces also in text you can use custom template tag like this https://gist.github.com/martinsvoboda/1bf965a8c6037c0fe1a88d89ea822df6. Usage:

```
{% load nospaces %}
{% nospaces %}
<strong>
    Hello
    this is text
</strong>
{% endnospaces %}
```

Renders

```
<strong>Hello this is text</strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

`{% spaceless %} YOUR CONTENT {% endspaceless %}`

Comment: as I said above: (and spaceless tag doesn't help), no much effect on the content: http://take.ms/qBy59, http://take.ms/BfAg8

Answer (score -1):

You can use `autoescape off` (with caution!):

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{data.content}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) for further information. You will also want to have a look at [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for my case. I did exactly as you said: http://take.ms/hiy1u, but it had no effect: http://take.ms/GLUuG