# How to split a long line in a Django template needed for formatting?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a line like this in a Django template:

```
{{ some_prefix }}{% if obj.obj_type == A_LONG_CONSTANT %}1{% elif obj.obj_type == A_LONG_CONSTANT %}2{% endif %}{{some_suffix}}:
```

where `some_prefix` might be a `(` or something longer, and `some_suffix` might be a `)` or maybe even empty.

I don't know how to break this up, since putting any whitespace in such a template make it look different in a browser.  Think "( hi )" instead of "(hi)".

Any suggestions?

You might say, "Put this in python, not Django templates."  However, I'm not sure how to split it up into a tag either.  It depends on the template context.

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8077609), but that's just renaming variable names, which might make this thing even more heinous.

I think there's probably nothing to do.

Comment: If you're worried about whitespace being inserted, would adding a [`spaceless`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) tag do the trick? Also potentially relevant: [How to avoid strange whitespaces in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29675216/11082165). Note the `nospace` tags in quick's answer.

Comment: Oh cool! I'm not sure if can would help here, because it's just space between text and not between tags. However, that's really great to know about.